# Same function for multimpe elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

i have this code:

https://jsfiddle.net/eur59yfa/6/

-Html and JS

```
     <body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="first">100</td>
<td class="second">20</td>
</tr>
</table>
    <script>
    document.body.onload = function(){
         var firstTdVal = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].innerHTML;
       var secondTdVal = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0].innerHTML;
       var valueToBeShown = parseInt(firstTdVal)/parseInt(secondTdVal);
       document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0].innerHTML = valueToBeShown ;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

The code works well,but i have a problem.For exemple,there will be others td's with ".third" class, ".fourth"... with different values:240,451..And all of those classes have to be divided to class ".second".Result of each should be shown in their own td.How to make this,by keeping code complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably more than you need, but this shows how to iterate over an array, create dynamic elements (and populate them) as well as how to dynamically assign classes and manage the CSS of the newly created elements.  Good luck.

```js
let thead = document.querySelector('table thead tr');
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
let dividends = ['first', 'third', 'fourth'];

// Dynamically Create Table Headers
dividends.forEach(x => {
  let new_th = document.createElement('th');
  
  // capitalize the class to use in the table header
  let title = x.replace(/\b([a-z])/g, (s) => {
    return s.toUpperCase()
  });
  
  // prepend "result-" to the class (e.g., "result-first")
  new_th.className = `result-${x}`;  
  new_th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${title} Result`));
  thead.appendChild(new_th);
});

// Dynamically Generate Result Values (and new table data cells)
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(row, index) {
  let divisor = +row.querySelector('.second').textContent;

  dividends.forEach(handle => {
    let dividend = +row.querySelector(`.${handle}`).textContent;
    let quotient = dividend / divisor;
    let new_cell = document.createElement('td');
    
    // append "-value" to the class (e.g., "first-value")
    new_cell.className = `${handle}-value`;
    new_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(quotient)); // add value
    row.appendChild(new_cell);
  });
});
```

```css
/* superfluous table styling */
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, "Segoe UI", "Calibri LIght", "Roboto Light", "Roboto", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
}
thead {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
td {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  text-align: left;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 4px;
}
/* end page + table styling */


/* demonstrates how to grab the first part of the class name */

[class^=result-] {
  color: #09c;
}
/* demonstrates how to grab the last part of the class name */

[class$=-value] {
  color: #900;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
      <th>Third</th>
      <th>Fourth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">100</td>
      <td class="second">10</td>
      <td class="third">300</td>
      <td class="fourth">400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">1000</td>
      <td class="second">10</td>
      <td class="third">3000</td>
      <td class="fourth">4000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by wirte your other values in own table rows and add a third column "result".

Then you can iterate over the table rows and easily access your values in each row:

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(row, index) {
  var first = row.querySelector('.first');
  var second = row.querySelector('.second');
  var result = row.querySelector('.result');

  console.log(first,second,result);

  result.textContent = parseInt(first.textContent)/parseInt(second.textContent);
});
```

I did a fork of your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36jpajk3/).